# Dynamic query to import from S3 bucket in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I am writing a stored procedure in pgAdmin (RDS instance on AWS) to dynamically import csv data from S3 bucket. I have all the necessary permissions and extensions created. I am passing the path within S3 bucket as a parameter for stored proc but query is treating the parameter as text as it is enclose in ''.

Sample query is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_import(
    _folderpath character varying,
    _dbname character varying)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare 
__path varchar(500);
__sql varchar(65000);
__region varchar(100);
__s3bucket varchar(100);
__tbltoload varchar(100);
__delimit varchar(100);
__query varchar (65000);

BEGIN
__tbltoload:='''public.table_name''';
__delimit := '(DELIMITER ''|'', NULL '''')';
__s3bucket = 'samplebucket';
__region := 'sample-region-1';
__path := _folderpath||'/'||_dbname||'/'||'folder1'||'/'||'000';
--__fullpath := '(||__s3bucket||','||__path||','||__region||')'||'';
__sql:='SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3';
__query := __sql || (__tbltoload,'''''','(DELIMITER ''''|'''', NULL '''''''')',(__s3bucket,__path,__region));
execute __query;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Error I am receiving is

> ERROR:  column "(DELIMITER ''|'', NULL '''')" does not exist

Below is the formation of the __query

> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('public.table1','',"(DELIMITER ''|'', NULL '''')","(samplebucket,_folderpath/_dbname/folder1/000,sample-region-1)");

Expected __query is :

> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('public.table1','','(DELIMITER ''|'', NULL '''')','(samplebucket,_folderpath/_dbname/folder1/000,sample-region-1)');

However, I am able to import the data when the path is hard coded. the quotes "" is not allowing it to execute as they are being treated as columns , instead "" needs to be replaced with '' in order to form the actual query to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Your fourth parameter to `table_import_from_s3` is the literal string `'(S3BucketName,__path,awsregion)'`. I'm not sure which overload of `table_import_from_s3` you want to call, but you either need to supply an actual s3 uri, or you should supply the bucket name, path, and region separately.

So assuming `S3BucketName` and `awsregion` are both variables that contain valid values, do either

```sql
aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'public.table',
   '',
   '(DELIMITER ''|'', NULL '''')',
   aws_commons.create_s3_uri(S3BucketName, __path, awsregion)
)
```

or

```sql
aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'public.table',
   '',
   '(DELIMITER ''|'', NULL '''')',
   S3BucketName,
   __path,
   awsregion
)
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

---

For the formatting issue, I would suggest you use a function like `FORMAT` to make things a bit clearer, as well as using dollar quotes in order to not go crazy with all the double/quadruple quoting. Just showing the bits from your function I changed:

```sql
-- added more double quotes here
__delimit := '(DELIMITER ''''|'''', NULL '''''''')';
-- by using dollar quoting here, everything looks much more normal
__query := FORMAT(
    $query$SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('%s', '', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')$query$,
    __tbltoload, __delimit, __s3bucket, __path, __region
);
```

And a `RAISE NOTICE` on `__query` returns this: `SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('public.table_name', '', '(DELIMITER ''|'', NULL '''')', 'samplebucket', 'myfolder/mydb/folder1/000', 'sample-region-1')`

Note I put the last 3 values as separate params rather than putting them in `()` because I think that's the version of the function you want, but you can always put those things back in, in the format string.

Comment: Thank you, the only issue I have is that I am getting " at  following places, how to get rid of those. "(DELIMITER '|', NULL '')" and "(s3bucket,__path,region)"). The section within " is being treated as column, how to fix?
I have made everything as a variable and forming a query using those variables. In the end I am running EXECUTE __queryname to run it.

Comment: @user3204086 Update your question with that *exact* code you're using, because if you use EXECUTE to run it then it's different from using SELECT. Put the code there and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: One more doubt : My destination table have 10 columns and the delimiter I am using is '|'. I have data available for 10 columns in csv file but one of the text column have '|' in it causing error "ERROR:  extra data after last expected column". How shall I handle that in the __query? Thanks in advance. @404

Comment: @user3204086 Not sure about that one off the top of my head. It may depend on how the data was exported. If you exported the data from postgres or similar and specified `|` as the delimiter, then any `|` in a field should be somehow escaped or something, in order for it to be differentiated from a delimiter. Or the field should be in quotes or something. If postgres isn't able to handle it "out of the box", then I suspect there's some issue in the csv file which doesn't allow differentiation of delimiter from regular character (or an issue with aws's function, but that seems unlikely).

Comment: the column with text and having pipe operator in between is enclosed within double quotes. Not sure why pgAdmin can't handle the data in "" as free text. Data for the column is like "I am going to school | but we have a holiday" | column2 |column 3